# Retrieve specific Uid from Selected ComboBoxItem in a ComboBox in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

how can i get the Uid from the ComboBoxItem that is selected by the User?

I have the following code in my XAML

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,163,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Background="White">
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Computing and IT" Uid="2001"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Electrical" Uid="2002"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Stationery" Uid="2003"/>
            <ComboBoxItem Content="Building" Uid="2004"/>
        </ComboBox>
```

and I'd like to get the Specific Uid, whichever is selected by the user in the ComboBox.

Comment: Uid is commonly used for localization.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746621.aspx . Is that your intent, or do you really want to have an ID for each ComboBoxItem?

Comment: I was actually looking to assign an ID to each ComboBoxItem, and then retrieve the ID for manipulation. But, anyway, i have figured it out thanks. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the `UID` by setting up a "`SectionChanged`" event on the `ComboBox` and then getting the value from the `ComboBox` item.

xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbCat" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="210,163,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="183" Background="White" SelectionChanged="cmbCat_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Computing and IT" Uid="2001"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Electrical" Uid="2002"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Stationery" Uid="2003"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Building" Uid="2004"/>
</ComboBox>
```

code behind:

```
private void cmbCat_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var comboBox = sender as ComboBox;
    if (null != comboBox)
    {
        var item = comboBox.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
        if (null != item)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Uid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Eventually, I achieved the same functionality by using something else. Although, i didn't use it , that worked. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

With no code behind, just add in your ComboBox node this attribute:

SelectedValuePath ="Uid"

So you can send Uid value to your viewModel with this other attribute:

SelectedValue="{Binding Path=MyViewModelProperty}"